# Why *RefMut<i32> can be used directly, but can not be assigned to a variable?

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust and reading Smart Pointer Chapter: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html.

Then I tried the following code (own code):

```rust
fn main () {
    let x = Rc::new(RefCell::new(5));
    let y = Rc::clone(&x);
    let z = Rc::clone(&x);

    {
        let mut tmp =  y.borrow_mut();
        *tmp = *tmp + 1;
    }

    println!("{} - {} - {}" , x.borrow(), y.borrow(), z.borrow());
}
```

It prints "6 - 6 - 6". Thus, the line `*tmp = *tmp + 1;` does increase one in that memory location. Somehow `*RefMut<i32>` can be considered as the memory location and its value at the same time.

But if I try to assign `*RefMut<i32>` to a variable, it won't work:

```rust
let mut tmp2 =  *y.borrow_mut();
tmp2 = tmp2 + 1;
```

`tmp2` is simply just a `i32` number type. Increasing it will have nothing to do with the memory location of `x`, `y`, `z`.

I think I can understand the most part. But I just don't really get it why `*tmp = *tmp + 1;` works if `*tmp` is just a i32 number type.

And is that possible to assign `*RefMut<i32>` to a variable so that I don't need to use `*` symbol in the plus operation?

### Edited

Thank @Locke's comment. I knew `*x = something` is a special syntax in Rust. It means "set the value to the memory location of x". Thus, I can not get rid of the `*` symbol because it's part of the syntax. I tried the following simple example and it proves that:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    let y = &mut x;
    *y = 7;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Incidentally, the official book does NOT mention this behavior and I am reading chapter 15.6 (nearly the end of the book).

Comment: `*x = y` roughly means "set the data `x` is refers to, to the value `y`". By using `*x` you are telling the compiler you want to interact with the data that `x` points to instead of the variable `x` itself.

Comment: @Locke thanks a lot for the answer. So `*variable =` is a special syntax in rust. `*variable` in the left of `=` assignment operator has a special meaning. OK, I got it.

Comment: @Locke PS: the official book should really talk about it in the early chapter. I don't see anything regarding this behavior. I am reading the end of Chapter 15 and nearly the end of the book. The book doesn't even talk about this simplest behavior.

Comment: it isn't special to Rust. This is an extremely common way to work with pointers across many (most?) languages that use pointers. Generally, pointers to are taken with `&x` and dereferencing using `*x`. The most prominent language to do this is probably C, but I would not be surprised if it was not the first. This method of working with pointers is so common that the book likely assumed the reader would already be familiar with the concept. Most people learning Rust for the first time already have experience with languages like C/C++.

Comment: Note that `let mut tmp2 =  &mut *y.borrow_mut()` works just fine, giving you a `&mut i32` which you can update with `*tmp = *tmp + 1`. You can think of `*bla` as "value at bla". Storing it to a variable simply copies the value, assigning to it modifies the underlying value, etc. Similar to that, `bla[i]` means "value at ith index of `bla`", `bla.field1` "value of field `field1` of bar", and all have equivalent semantics.